# Visual Studio 2010: any way to make font settings solution dependent?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I know how to set the font in Options -> Fonts and Colors. It would be nice to be able to have font settings per solution so that 1 solution could be set to Monaco and another one set to Consolas for example.

Why? Sometimes when you have several solutions open, particularly when you have dragged code windows onto multiple screens, it would be a nice tip-off to instantly see which project you  are editing by seeing the different font.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1212092/visual-studio-per-solution-indentation-settings) a question/answer on SO which might be the solution for you.