# Code indenting specified at project/solution level rather than global

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Visual Studio, per solution indentation settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1212092/visual-studio-per-solution-indentation-settings)

So I have a situation where I am working on a code base from some contractors that has its code indented to 4 spaces, every other project I work with is 2 spaces.

What is my best strategy for switching back and forth between the 2 indenting standards, Visual Studio 2010 sets this globally not at a solution level.

Comment: The Industry standard for Visual Studio is 4 spaces.  Ensure your contractors are adhering to your (and the industry) standard.

Comment: @Mitch, that's simply not true here in Oz at least. Every place I have worked has 2 spaces as default ( and that is in C#, C++, Delphi and Java) The times that we have used 4 is rare, and usually because someone at the start forgot to change the default.

Comment: 2 spaces is the java standard. Everywhere I've worked (in Oz) uses 4 spaces for C#. The MS standard is 4 spaces I believe

Comment: Oh, by the way. The standard here at Quest is 2 spaces, it's the contractors who are on 4.

Comment: in any case, its done. and I do not want to alter 3000+ files for just an indent irritation. What I am after is a workable solution to switch back and forth at a solution level.

Comment: @Mitch, No not originally a Java shop, though we do use Java for some things. Our Oz lab was largely Delphi once upon a time, and probably where the 2 space standard comes from originally. (I come from a Delphi background, that's most likely why I personally have mostly seen 2 space code standards...even in C# projects) But anyway this isn't the point. The point is I have a large code base that we now need to use and maintain, which is different indenting from our standard, its impractical to change the entire source to our standard and a PITA for me to have to keep switching.

Comment: @Mitch: Starting a religious debate about "the one true indentation standard" (hint: it isn't two spaces, four spaces, nor even three spaces) isn't helping @Tim manage his code any better.

Comment: @Ben Voigt : I'm not starting any religious debate. The MS .NET standard is 4 spaces. In addition I've attempted to help Tim by answering below. That's all folks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Visual Studio SDK provides access to this setting: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.package.languagepreferences.indentsize.aspx

It seems quite likely that someone's already developed an addin to manage indentation settings, maybe even listed in the [Addins/Extensions Gallery](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/), also viewable inside VS2010.

This one seems like a good fit:

> **[Indentation Matcher Extension](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/77b317a9-1a94-4ae0-bd15-d46a3195219f)**
>
> This extension detects the current file's indentation settings and automatically resets the corresponding Tools->Options settings to match.  It also detects mixed tabs and spaces on file load and file save, then offers options to make indentation consistent.

Comment: Brilliant ! just what I was after. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You could on opening an offending file (i.e. one that doesn't conform to your standard), press `CTRL+K, CTRL+D`, which will reformat to the current Visual Studio settings.  Not perfect, but might reduce the 'pain'. You might even be able to automate this through Visual Studio.

In addition, you would have to ask your contractors to change there standard; might be difficult to convince them (I know I wouldn't!).

Have you tried creating two [Custom Editor settings files](http://www.andrewconnell.com/blog/archive/2006/08/25/3995.aspx), and loading the relevant one when required?

Also, as mentioned in the comments, many source code Diff tools can ignore whitespace, so converting files when opened should not cause check-in differences.

Comment: Having a code standard with either 2 or 4 spaces is perfectly fine as far as I am concerned. I don't have a problem with their 4 spaces, except that all my other projects are 2 spaces. Its VS that is the limiting factor here because it auto-indents, its not the code standards. For me to say to anyone change your 3000+ files because its irritating to change a global setting back and forth is just plain madness.

Comment: @Tim Jarvis: I'm not suggesting you change them all, only the ones you open....

Comment: the problem with that is these files will be collaborated on, If I change something and change the indent, the diff on the file will be the whole file, or at least a bigger proportion than the actual change, then they go in an change something and alter the indentation again, the diffs are all over the place. Thats not good especially when you are working in different time zones (these guys are in India) we both need to see the real diffs. So it looks like I will just have to change my setting back and forth, but that is a pretty poor manual solution.

Comment: use a diff tool that ignores whitespace: many do.