# Per solution new line options for braces in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, editorconfig

Through [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11455621/419956) to a question on per-solution indentation settings for Visual Studio I found out that the EditorConfig format is supported for VS 2017.

What I cannot find is how to use EditorConfig (or failing that: any alternative) to set "New line options for braces" on a per-solution basis.

Here's the relevant settings from Visual Studio:

[image: new lines for braces settings dialog]

These settings are persisted on my Visual Studio 2017 *account*, which is really annoying since I use defaults for my pet projects, but the project I mainly work on uses Egyptian braces style. If I change these settings on my work PC they will be synched to my home PC every time, and vice versa.

Can EditorConfig be used to have per-solution settings for "New line options for braces"? Failing that, is there another way to handle this?

Answer (score 2):

I believe these are controlled by the `csharp_new_line_before_open_brace` property in `.editorconfig`. Unfortunately the closest thing I have seen to documentation on the properties used by roslyn is the [source code](http://source.roslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Workspaces/Formatting/CSharpFormattingOptions.cs,ffb4560e185e6686,references) and the [issue](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/pull/15020) under which they were added.

My experience with getting visual studio to use a `.editorconfig` file however, has been a bit hit and miss. Sometimes visual studio will ignore the file without giving any reason.